# C++ for structure in vectors access index or use reference instead value

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I assume that if I ve got, for example:

```
vector<string> myVector;
myVector.push_back("Camel");
myVector.push_back("is");
myVector.push_back("a");
myVector.push_back("noble");
myVector.push_back("animal");
```

And I do:

```
for (string val : myVector){
    val = "empty";
}
```

It does not replace value in vector since it has copied content to a new string.

I assume I can do

```
for (int i=0; i<myVector.size(); i++) {
    myVector[i] = "empty";
}
```

It will perform the behaviour.

But well. My question is:

There exist any other  structure similar to first case where I can say "Pick the reference of the value in the vector instead of you copy value to a new variable" then I can directly affect to vector values instead and having the `for (class value : vector)` typing model?

Or Best practices for the example without use any of the cases I mentioned? Iterator?

Comment: In this particular case, `std::fill` will accomplish the task and attach a meaningful name to it.

Comment: Very good to know @chris but sadly I wanted to simplify the example code like that. But I was looking for  how to access by reference. Anyways I will have in mind that 'fill' when I need it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, I figured that wouldn't be a useful answer for most future visitors, but might help the odd person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your range based for loop to initialize a reference to each item:

```
for (string& val : myVector){
    val = "empty";
}
```

Now the vector's items are modified in-place. The type of the "item" can be anything for which...

```
<item-type> declarator = *itr;
```

... is valid when `itr` is an iterator of the container.

Comment: Worked as intended! It was mine bad because I think now it was a little obvious but is good to have clear it is like that. Thank you very much @StoryTeller! accepting answer in 5 mins.. you was so fast :)